# I've broken the search using a wildcard

Tags: bug, search, tag-search, wildcards

Today I managed to break one of the two search bars in the screen:

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

- Search for [`[feature-request] [status*]`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D%20%5Bstatus*%5D)

  [image]

  This automatically converts your wildcard tag to all options. If your wildcard tag is the first tag this doesn't happen.
- Go to the top search bar (the black one), and change your query to: [`[status-completed] or [status-bydesign] or [status-declined] or [status-norepro] or [status-review] or [status-deferred] or [status-planned] or [status-reproduced] and [feature-request]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-completed%5D+or+%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+or+%5Bstatus-declined%5D+or+%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+or+%5Bstatus-review%5D+or+%5Bstatus-deferred%5D+or+%5Bstatus-planned%5D+or+%5Bstatus-reproduced%5D+and++%5Bfeature-request%5D)

  Spoiler tip: I included an `AND` operator between the last status tag
  and the feature-request tag.

  [image]

  This unlocks the white search bar, which looks editable, and should be editable, but really isn't. I can place my cursor in it, but it doesn't accept any inputs. Typed or pasted.

Using Firefox 68.5.0 esr and Chrome 80.0.3987.163 on macOS 10.14.6

Answer (score 2):

> Spoiler tip: I included an AND operator between the last status tag and the feature-request tag. This unlocks the white search bar

This is a big misconception.

- You can type [any ordinary text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=unlock+white+search+bar) in search bar to unlock white search bar.
- That is not AND operator actually it is searching "and" sting. [Verify it from your own screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwJX9.png) ! In other words, when you type `[tag1] and [tag2]` it will search for "`and` tagged with [tag1](/questions/tagged/tag1) [tag2](/questions/tagged/tag2)"

> I've broken the search using a wildcard

Nothing to do with wild card here.

Steps to reproduce: Copy any long text (>180 characters) and paste it in search bar, then press enter and you'll get white search bar of having same issue.

#### The real problem according to me is:

Maximum length of characters allowed for **Black** bar is **240**  Whereas
Maximum length of characters allowed for **White** bar is **140**

Here is the properties of search bar I have found by using [Inspector of Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector): (check maxlength)

- For black bar:

  ```
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search on Meta Stack Exchange…" value="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="240" class="s-input s-input__search js-search-field " aria-label="Search" aria-controls="top-search" data-controller="s-popover" data-action="focus->s-popover#show" data-s-popover-placement="bottom-start">
  ```
- For white bar:

  ```
    <input name="q" class="grid--cell fl1 s-input" type="text" maxlength="140">
  ```

So, when you type more than 180 characters (The expansion of `[stauts*]` is 181 character long) in black bar, you'll get white bar overflowed and until you delete characters to meet criteria of White bar, it will not allow you to enter any character.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with the [Searchbar & Nav Improvements userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#searchbar--nav-improvements):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No repro FF 68.7b1, Android.

Instead I get this [marquee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) banner:

[image: start]
[image: end]

So it's not "broken" it clearly says what its complaint is.

Comment: Then the implementation of the banner is broken :)